# MySql Date Query Incorrect result

Tags: mysql, sql

When i run the below query, it returns all the results for dates falling within `Date_add (CURDATE() AND CURDATE(), interval 30 day)` but does not include results for `Date_sub (CURDATE() AND CURDATE(), interval 15 day)`

I know the data exists when I query with exact clause of `deadline = '2015-01-15'`

What could be wrong?

```
SELECT bug_id, 
       bug_status, 
       resolution, 
       short_desc, 
       deadline 
FROM   bugs 
WHERE  bug_status IN ( 'RESOLVED' ) 
       AND deadline BETWEEN Curdate() AND Date_add(Curdate(), interval 30 day) 
        OR deadline BETWEEN Curdate() AND Date_sub(Curdate(), interval 15 day)
```

Comment: Side note: depending on the types involved (ie, if `deadline` is a timestamp with fractional seconds), you probably [want to avoid using `BETWEEN` anyways](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common). (This is more than just an SQL Server problem - it actually applies to all positive, contiguous-range types, due to how numbers are represented)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rand for `between` is ordered.  So, the second `between` is not correct.  In addition, you probably want parentheses:

```
WHERE  bug_status IN ( 'RESOLVED' ) AND
       (deadline BETWEEN Curdate() AND Date_add(Curdate(), interval 30 day) OR
        deadline BETWEEN Date_sub(Curdate(), interval 15 day)  AND Curdate()
       )
```

I mean, you might not want parentheses, so the query would then be:

```
WHERE  (bug_status IN ( 'RESOLVED' ) AND
        deadline BETWEEN Curdate() AND Date_add(Curdate(), interval 30 day)
       ) OR
       deadline BETWEEN Date_sub(Curdate(), interval 15 day)  AND Curdate()
```

In this case, the parentheses are redundant but they clarify the logic.

Answer (score 1):

`between`'s arguments should always be `value BETWEEN low AND high`. If you flip `low` and `high`, it'll return `false`. Moreover, you can unify both conditions to one:

```
deadline BETWEEN Date_sub(Curdate(), interval 15 day) AND 
                 Date_add(Curdate(), interval 30 day)
```